# Devise 3.5.3 install command returns "already in use" routing error, but routes.rb is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm building a Rails 4.2.5 Application, and I want to use Devise. I have already included devise in my gemfile as:

```
gem 'Devise'
```

After doing the bundle install command, I proceeded to do:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

As per the installation instructions on the repo. At this point, I get the following error:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option,  
or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same
naming.
```

Checking other related StackOverflow answers, they've all had the same mistake: They indeed had a duplicate route in their routes.rb file. My problem is that my routes.rb file is COMPLETELY EMPTY! it only has the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

end
```

And just to re-confirm, I ran rake routes and the terminal returns that I have no routes defined. So what am I doing wrong? How can it possibly complain about an existing route when there are none defined? All help will be appreciated, thank you very much!

[This is the link to the GitHub repo, if necessary.](https://github.com/guerragiancarlo8/GroopiePets)

Comment: You need to include `devise_for :users` in your routes file

Comment: @RichPeck still the same error. I even tried straight-out creating rails generate devise User, and still not functioning.

Comment: Hmm, do you have a github repo I could look at?

Comment: https://github.com/guerragiancarlo8/GroopiePets

Comment: You've got no models?

Comment: You should run `rails generate devise User` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

Comment: nope. It's a brand-new app i literally created 30 mins ago. I was installing everything and just as I was gonna generate my Users devise model I got this error. So nope, no models, controllers, views yet.

Comment: And i did run rails generate devise User, but I still get the routes error.

Comment: Alright, try adding the model manually `class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable `

Comment: Tried it. After running rake db:migrate I get an 'undefined method for "User"' error.

Comment: I've just cloned your app from github, removed `devise_for :users` in config/routes.rb and then executed `rails g devise:install` and everything is fine.

Comment: hmm that's what I did before you suggesting I add devise_for :users. Must be something with my system then. I'll try to keep digging.

Comment: I didn't suggest you to install devise manually, it's bad practice. Try to create brand-new app and then try to install devise. If something will go wrong, then you need to reinstall devise.